# I don't understand how trap works

Tags: powershell, powershell-trap

I'm trying to make a trap command that traps the exception that a file is not found. This is the code:

```
Trap {
  Clear-Host
  Write-Host "The file you are looking for does not exist"
}

Get-ItemProperty C:\fake
```

Am I misunderstanding how to do this?

Comment: `Get-ItemProperty C:\fake -ErrorAction Stop`

Comment: I suggest you work through `get-help trap -sh`

Comment: @user2120893 Could you update your question to include the actual problems you faced, or how the behavior did not match your expectations? This will help other users with similar problems find (and upvote ;-) your question E.g., did the trap fail to catch errors; Did you have trouble with how the error bubbled up to the caller? Etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traps only execute on terminating errors (errors that stop the pipeline), so first you'll need change the ErrorAction behavior of the offending cmdlet:

```
Trap {
  Clear-Host
  Write-Host "The file you are looking for does not exist"
}

Get-ItemProperty C:\fake -ErrorAction Stop
```

To suppress the error record from subsequently bubbling up to the caller, return from the current scope from inside the trap:

```
Trap {
  Clear-Host
  Write-Host "The file you are looking for does not exist"
  return
}

Get-ItemProperty C:\fake -ErrorAction Stop
```

---

In order to not have to specify the `-ErrorAction Stop` parameter argument explicitly all the time, set the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable at the start of your script/function:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
```

or use the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` hashtable to set it for specific cmdlets:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Get-ItemProperty:ErrorAction'] = 'Stop'
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Do-OtherStuff:ErrorAction'] = 'Stop'
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Set-*:ErrorAction'] = 'Stop'
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't really understand my books explanation of how traps worked